# Spark Sql cast null to complex StructType

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I've dataframe with following schema, explode_outer works fine on array columns if it's not null. Is there a way to replace null with default schema fields for that column, so explode will work with default value for the null field with same schema as original if data were present.

Schema :

```
 |-- building: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- doorAccess: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- securityGroup: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- loginDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- additionalInfo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- member_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sessionId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rack: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cable: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- server: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

With this schema code works fine with sample data.

```
{"server":{"name":"fifit","id":"1234"},"event":{"id":"sample1","timestamp":"2018-12-18T21:48:31.964Z"},"rack":[{"cable":[{"code":"","color":""}],"number":0,"name":""}],"building":[{"name":"name1","doorAccess":[{"key":"1","value":"2"}],"securityGroup":[{"field":"f1","name":"n1"},{"field":"f2","name":"n2"}]}],"loginDetails":{"sessionId":"SESSSION","additionalInfo":{"member_id":"1999359149"}}}
```

But in the input data column(rack) if it receives null, explode doesn't work as it's expecting array or map type of column.

```
{"server":{"name":"fifit","id":"1234"},"event":{"id":"sample1","timestamp":"2018-12-18T21:48:31.964Z"},"rack":null,"building":[{"name":"name1","doorAccess":[{"key":"1","value":"2"}],"securityGroup":[{"field":"f1","name":"n1"},{"field":"f2","name":"n2"}]}],"loginDetails":{"sessionId":"SESSSION","additionalInfo":{"member_id":"1999359149"}}}
```

I've tried to replace column using below.

```java
StructField[] structFields = new StructField[3];
      StructField a1 = new StructField("cableData", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType), false, Metadata.empty());
      StructField a2 = new StructField("number", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
      StructField a3 = new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
      structFields[0] = a1;
      structFields[1] = a2;
      structFields[2] = a3;
StructType schema  = new StructType(structFields);

Dataset<Row> m = jsonDF.withColumn("rack", when(col("rack").isNull(), array().cast(schema))); <-- Cannot cast to nested type. Not sure WrappedArray will help me here.
```

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String avroSchema =
        "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"experiments\",\"namespace\":\"dummy\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"server\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"record_data\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"name of application\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"ISO 8601 UTC timestamp from the message producer\",\"default\":null}]},\"doc\":\"record information\",\"default\":{}},{\"name\":\"event\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"event_data\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"Unique id of record: current ISO timestamp with the session id appended\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"The time this event was received by the server. (Will be set by the server, so applications should leave blank)\",\"default\":null}]},\"doc\":\"event information\",\"default\":{}},{\"name\":\"rack\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"rack_mapping\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"cable\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"color_data\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"color\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"value of the error thrown\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"code\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"reason for the error thrown\",\"default\":\"\"}],\"default\":{}}}],\"doc\":\"experiments error data schema\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"number\",\"type\":\"int\",\"doc\":\"Qualified context number\",\"default\":0},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"qualified experiment for page\",\"default\":\"\"}],\"default\":{}},\"default\":[]}],\"doc\":\"\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"building\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"recordViewMap\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"context condition qualified for device\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"doorAccess\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"treatmentDelivered_mapping\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"key\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"Key name of treatment parameter (e.g. buttonColor)\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"Value of treatment parameter (e.g. blue)\",\"default\":\"\"}],\"default\":{}},\"default\":[]}],\"doc\":\"\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"securityGroup\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"SecuryMap\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"field\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"value of the error thrown\",\"default\":\"\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"reason for the error thrown\",\"default\":\"\"}],\"default\":{}},\"default\":[]}],\"doc\":\"\",\"default\":null}],\"default\":{}},\"default\":[]}],\"doc\":\"\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"loginDetails\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"identity_data\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"sessionId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"Session id as a random hex number in the range: 0xAAAAC8 - 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFE0\",\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"additionalInfo\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"map\",\"values\":\"string\"}],\"doc\":\"additional data pertaining to notifications - can change dynamically based on notification type\",\"default\":null}]},\"doc\":\"\",\"default\":{}}]}";
        Schema schema3 = Schema.parse(avroSchema);
        JsonAvroConverter converter = new JsonAvroConverter();

        String x =
        "{\"server\":{\"name\":\"fifit\",\"id\":\"1234\"},\"event\":{\"id\":\"sample1\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-12-18T21:48:31.964Z\"},\"rack\":[{\"cable\":[{\"code\":\"\",\"color\":\"\"}],\"number\":0,\"name\":\"\"}],\"building\":[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"doorAccess\":[{\"key\":\"1\",\"value\":\"2\"}],\"securityGroup\":[{\"field\":\"f1\",\"name\":\"n1\"},{\"field\":\"f2\",\"name\":\"n2\"}]}],\"loginDetails\":{\"sessionId\":\"SESSSION\",\"additionalInfo\":{\"member_id\":\"1999359149\"}}}";
        byte[] a = x.getBytes();

        GenericData.Record record = converter.convertToGenericDataRecord(a, schema3);

        String ds = record.toString();
        List<String> jsonData = Arrays.asList(
            ds);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("server Name")
            .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<String> jsonD = spark.createDataset(jsonData, Encoders.STRING());

        Dataset<Row> jsonDF = spark.read().json(jsonD);

        Dataset<Row> y = jsonDF.select(col("server"), explode_outer(col("rack")).alias("rack"), col("building").alias("building"), col("event"), col("loginDetails"));
        Dataset<Row> z = y.select(col("server"), col("rack"), col("loginDetails"), col("event"), explode_outer(y.col("building")).alias("building"));
        Dataset<Row> a1 = z.select(col("server"), col("loginDetails"), col("event"), explode_outer(col("rack.cable")).alias("rack_cable"), col("building"),
            col("rack.name").alias("rack_name"), col("rack.number").alias("rack_number"), col("building.name").alias("building_name"), col("building.securityGroup").alias("building_securityGroup"));
        Dataset<Row> a2 = a1.select(col("server"), col("loginDetails"), col("event"), col("rack_cable"), col("rack_name"), col("rack_number"), col("building_name"), explode_outer(col("building.doorAccess")).alias("building_doorAccess"), col("building_securityGroup"));
        Dataset<Row> a3 = a2.select(col("server"), col("loginDetails"), col("event"), col("building_name"), col("rack_cable"), col("rack_name"), col("rack_number"), col("building_doorAccess"), explode_outer(col("building_securityGroup")).alias("building_securityGroup"));
        String x1 = Utils.flattenSchema(a3.schema(), null);
                # FlattenSchema will flatten all structtype fields.
        System.out.println(")))))" + x1);
        a3.registerTempTable("flattenTable");
        System.out.println(a3.showString(10, 0, false));
        Dataset<Row> flattenData = spark.sql("SELECT " + x1 + " FROM flattenTable");
        System.out.println(flattenData.toJSON().toString());

    }
```

Here's what I'm expecting, if col("rack") is null.

```
server_id,server_name,loginDetails_additionalInfo_member_id,loginDetails_sessionId,event_id,event_timestamp,building_name,rack_cable_code,rack_cable_color,rack_name,rack_number,building_doorAccess_key,building_doorAccess_value,building_securityGroup_field,building_securityGroup_name
1234,fifit,1999359149,SESSSION,sample1,2018-12-18T21:48:31.964Z,name1,"","","",0,1,2,f1,n1
1234,fifit,1999359149,SESSSION,sample1,2018-12-18T21:48:31.964Z,name1,"","","",0,1,2,f2,n2
```

Comment: if you want the nullable columns to show up in you exploded Dataframe you will have to provide it with the output schema.

Comment: @Aaron can you provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using UDF to convert null column to StructType

```java
        List<DataClass> cd = new ArrayList<>();
        cd.add(new DataClass());
        StructField[] structFields = new StructField[3];
        StructField[] structFields1 = new StructField[2];
        structFields1[1]=new StructField("color", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFields1[0]=new StructField("code", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
        StructType ss = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields1);
        StructField a11 = new StructField("cable", DataTypes.createArrayType(ss), false, Metadata.empty());
        StructField a31 = new StructField("number", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
        StructField a21 = new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty());
        structFields[0] = a11;
        structFields[1] = a21;
        structFields[2] = a31;
        StructType s = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);
        ArrayType arr = DataTypes.createArrayType(s);
        mode = udf((WrappedArray s) -> cd, arr);

/*DataClass*/

 class DataClass implements Serializable {
    public String name;
    public String  number;

    List<Cable> cable = new ArrayList<>();
    public DataClass() {
        List<Cable> cables;
        cables = new ArrayList<>();
        cables.add(new Cable());
        Row row = RowFactory.create(cables.toArray());
        this.cable.add(new Cable());
        this.number = "";
        this.name = "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new String("Rack:" +this.name + ", "+ this.number + ", " + this.cable);
    }

    static class Cable implements Serializable {
        public String color;
        public String code;

        public Cable() {
            this.color = "";
            this.code = "";
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return new String("Cable:" +this.color + ", "+ this.code);
        }
    }
}
```